# My code is working on python 2 but not on python 3, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code

```
from __future__ import print_function

upper = []
lower = []
even = []
odd = []

def separator(a):
    print(a)
    if a.isalpha():
        if a.isupper():
            upper.append(a)
        else:
            lower.append(a)
    else:
        if int(a)%2 == 0:
            even.append(a)
        else:
            odd.append(a)
    return 
list = ['S','o','t','']   
map(separator,list)       

upper.sort()
lower.sort()
even.sort()
odd.sort()

t = lower+upper+odd+even
print(t)
```

Here when I run the code, It works fine on python 2 but same doesn't works on python 3. *seperator* function is not getting called from map.

Comment: Note that creating a list for its side effects is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` [works differently](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) in Python 2 than in Python 3. In Python 2, the map will run and produce a list. In Python 3, it simply returns an iterator, which you will have to iterate over to get the results.

Using `map` the way you have here is not really idiomatic anyway, so I would suggest that you just use a "normal" loop.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `map` returns an iterator – it will only call the function on each element as you iterate over the result. To get around this, you can cast the result of `map` to a `tuple` or `list` so that the iterator gets consumed (and thus, executed).

```
tuple(map(separator,list))
```

Note, however, that your code is pretty bad style – `map` should (generally) produce new data as opposed to editing global variables.

Comment: Note: The Pythonic replacement for `map` here would just be `for x in list: separator(x)`. Of course, you also wouldn't name a variable `list` (particularly in global scope, since it shadows the `list` constructor from there on for all code executed after that line).